# how to create highchart with y axis with character vector

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am creating this chart in highchart using the R package `highcharter` but it’s not working because the y axis is a character:

This is my code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

hchart(
    mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("rowname"),
    "scatter",
    hcaes(x = mpg, y = rowname),
    colorByPoint = TRUE
)
```

How can I create a chart like this?

Comment: Do you need `scatter` or `bar` plot?  `hchart(
  mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("rowname"),
  "bar",
  hcaes(y = mpg, x = rowname),
  colorByPoint = TRUE
)`  A scatter plot may not be suitable in this case

Comment: Or if you want points, `hchart(
  mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("rowname"),
  "point",
  hcaes(y = mpg, x = rowname),
  colorByPoint = TRUE
)`

Comment: Hi @akrun !! Why did you change the axis? On y Axis should be names and x Axis integers

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for?  If you want to do a scatter plot between two numeric column and label it with rowname `mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("rowname") %>%
hchart( "scatter",
       hcaes(x = mpg, y = qsec, group = rowname),
       showInLegend = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I get it from the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.data) we can't have a categorical variable on the y axis in case of `scatter`. However, a workaround would be to map an index on `y` then set the category labels via `hc_yAsis`:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

y_axis_categories <- rownames(mtcars)

mtcars %>% 
  rowid_to_column("id") %>%
  mutate(id = id - 1) |> # JS indexing starts at 0
  hchart(
  "scatter",
  hcaes(x = mpg, y = id),
  colorByPoint = TRUE
) %>%  
  hc_yAxis(categories = y_axis_categories)
```

[image]